# Not able to display updated values from the database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm retrieving and displaying the list of text depending on whichever button/catagory is clicked/selected.
I'm also trying to let user enter the text and that that will be saved in the database and will be displayed at the bottom of all the current text of the active/selected catagory thats being displayed.But i'm having a problem in this part.I tried to remove all the child views from parent views by getting number of elements from the database then i tried to insert the data into database and at last i'm trying to get all the elements after inserting new one and build all the child view.While doing this i'm getting ArrayOutOfBound Exception.I'm not sure why i'm getting this error and also whether this is an efficient way to accomplish this.Please guide me.

```
public class Independent extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
public TextView[] mainText;
public LinearLayout[] textLayout;
public LinearLayout textLayoutContainer;
public ScrollView scrollView;
EditText tv;
int x, y, z;
public String catagory;

public Independent() {
    catagory = "";
}// End of Constructor

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.catagories_list);
    textLayoutContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.text_linearlayout);
    scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    Button addTextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_add);
    Button editTextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_edit);
    Button deleteTextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_delete);
    addTextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    editTextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    deleteTextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton generalButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ImageButton foodButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    generalButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    foodButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.imageButton1:
        if (catagory == "General") {
            Dialog gend = new Dialog(Independent.this);
            gend.setTitle("Message");
            TextView tv2 = new TextView(Independent.this);
            tv2.setText("General catagory is already selected.");
            gend.setContentView(tv2);
            gend.setCancelable(true);
            gend.show();
        } else {
            catagory = "General";
            IndependentDB genData = IndependentDB.getInstance();
            genData.open(this);
            ArrayList<TextHolder> genList = new ArrayList<TextHolder>();
            genList = genData.getAllTextFromGenT();
            genData.close();
            x = genList.size();
            String xstr = new StringBuilder().append(x).toString();
            System.out.println(xstr);
            mainText = new TextView[x];
            textLayout = new LinearLayout[x];
            if (!genList.isEmpty()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                    TextHolder firstOne = genList.get(i);
                    String text = firstOne.getText();
                    System.out.println("2");
                    mainText[i] = new TextView(this);
                    System.out.println("3");
                    mainText[i].setId(i);
                    System.out.println("4");
                    mainText[i].setText("Text");
                    System.out.println("5");
                    mainText[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    System.out.println("6");
                    mainText[i].setTextSize(20);
                    System.out.println("7");
                    mainText[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    System.out.println("8");
                    mainText[i].setText(text);
                    System.out.println("9");
                    textLayout[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
                    System.out.println("10");
                    textLayout[i].setId(i);
                    System.out.println("11");
                    textLayout[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    System.out.println("12");
                    textLayout[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    System.out.println("13");
                    textLayout[i].addView(mainText[i]);
                    System.out.println("14");
                    textLayoutContainer.addView(textLayout[i]);
                    System.out.println("15");
                }
            }
        }
        break;
case R.id.b_add:
    textLayoutContainer.removeAllViews();
        tv = new EditText(this);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Please eneter the text below.");
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setView(tv);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Save",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        boolean Success = true;
                        Editable ttv = tv.getText();
                        final String stringttv = new StringBuilder()
                                .append(ttv).toString();
                        if (stringttv == "") {
                            Dialog mTag = new Dialog(Independent.this);
                            mTag.setTitle("Missing Text");
                            TextView tv2 = new TextView(Independent.this);
                            tv2.setText("Please enter the text you would like to add.");
                            mTag.setContentView(tv2);
                            mTag.setCancelable(true);
                            mTag.show();
                        } else {
                            try {
                                if (catagory == "General") {
                                    //Clearing View
                                    IndependentDB idb0 = IndependentDB
                                            .getInstance();
                                    idb0.open(Independent.this);
                                    ArrayList<TextHolder> gentList = new ArrayList<TextHolder>();
                                    gentList = idb0.getAllTextFromGenT();
                                    int v = gentList.size();
                                    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
                                        textLayout[i].removeAllViews();
                                    }// End of for loop
                                    idb0.close();

                                    //Inserting new text
                                    IndependentDB idb1 = IndependentDB
                                            .getInstance();
                                    idb1.open(Independent.this);
                                    idb1.insertEventInGenT(stringttv);
                                    idb1.close();

                                    //Getting the updated DB values/text
                                    IndependentDB idb2 = IndependentDB
                                    .getInstance();
                                    idb2.open(Independent.this);
                                    //iddb.insertEventInGenT(stringttv);
                                    ArrayList<TextHolder> genTList = new ArrayList<TextHolder>();
                                    genTList = idb2.getAllTextFromGenT();
                                    System.out.println("check1");
                                    int w = genTList.size();
                                    System.out.println("check2");
                                    if (!genTList.isEmpty()) {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < w ; i++) {
                                            TextHolder firstOne = genTList
                                                    .get(i);
                                            System.out.println("check3");
                                            String text = firstOne
                                                    .getText();
                                            System.out.println("check4");
                                            mainText[i] = new TextView(
                                                    Independent.this);
                                            mainText[i].setId(i);
                                            mainText[i].setText("Text");
                                            mainText[i]
                                                    .setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                            mainText[i].setTextSize(20);
                                            mainText[i]
                                                    .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                                            mainText[i].setText(text);
                                            textLayout[i] = new LinearLayout(
                                                    Independent.this);
                                            textLayout[i].setId(i);
                                            textLayout[i]
                                                    .setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                            textLayout[i]
                                                    .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                                            textLayout[i]
                                                    .addView(mainText[i]);
                                            textLayoutContainer
                                                    .addView(textLayout[i]);
                                        }// End of for loop
                                    }// End of If statement
                                    idb2.close();
                                }
}catch (Exception e) {
                                Success = false;
                                String error = e.toString();
                                Dialog d = new Dialog(Independent.this);
                                d.setTitle("Error");
                                TextView tv = new TextView(Independent.this);
                                tv.setText(error);
                                d.setContentView(tv);
                                d.show();
                            } finally {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        break;

    case R.id.b_edit:
        break;

    case R.id.b_delete:
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Sorry for not posting the stack trace before.Now I removed the following line of code:

```
IndependentDB idb0 = IndependentDB
                                            .getInstance();
                                    idb0.open(Independent.this);
                                    ArrayList<TextHolder> gentList = new ArrayList<TextHolder>();
                                    gentList = idb0.getAllTextFromGenT();
                                    int v = gentList.size();
                                    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
                                        textLayout[i].removeAllViews();
                                    }// End of for loop
                                    idb0.close();
```

I'm not getting ArrayOutOfBound Exception anymore but i'm still not able to retrieve the last inserted value.

Following the last four line of logcat messages where the stack trace message showed up:

```
01-17 14:48:55.617: I/System.out(408): check3
01-17 14:48:55.617: I/System.out(408): check4
01-17 14:48:55.628: I/System.out(408): null null     [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@44f9cd28
01-17 14:48:56.309: D/dalvikvm(304): GC_EXPLICIT freed 208 objects / 9952 bytes in 766ms
01-17 14:49:05.149: D/dalvikvm(134): GC_EXPLICIT freed 719 objects / 40696 bytes in 77ms
```

Comment: So, you have an exception, and we are supposed to gess where, in this giant piece of code, it happens? At least provide the stack trace and tell us which line in the code is the line that causes the exception.

Comment: sorry for not posting stack trace before.I edited my question and added the stack trace also i did made some changes and the ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception is gone but i'm still not able to retrieve and display the last newly added value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem.
i'm inserting the newly added value into the database but not depending on the database to retrieve and display it but i created new textview and i'm directly getting the text from edittext and setting it to new textview that i created and displaying it.it worked :)