# How can i display the updated values from the database-Android

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I want to display the the newly added values from the database in android.
Like current values are being displayed as a list of TextViews at the start of the application now when user clicks add button and enters new value(s) this value are added to the database and are immediately displayed at the bottom of the current values.Can anyone please tell me if there is any way to accomplish this.Thank you.

Comment: These TextViews, are they in a ListView? If so, what type of adapter is the ListView backed by?

Comment: They are in LinerLayout and are generated dynamically based on the number of elements retrieved from the database.I used term List as in non-coding term sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please post your code, that way it will easier for us to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: i don't have code written for this.I have wrote the code for something similar where i'm trying to achieve the same but the approach is more complex and i'm having trouble displaying the newly added value.Following is the link to the question with the code posted by me earlier here>>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900268/not-able-to-display-updated-values-from-the-database-in-android 
I'm looking for more simple approach if it exist.thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a LinearLayout to display a "list" of TextViews, you will have to manually create a new TextView and add it to the LinearLayout when the new value is added to the database.

Comment: hello elijah thanks for the reply.
i'm doing exactly the same as you suggested but not having luck.Here is the question with the code that i posted here earlier >>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900268/not-able-to-display-updated-values-from-the-database-in-android

Generating TextViews is not the problem in my case but the problem is in retrieving the last newly added value

Comment: well -- if you already have the previous values displayed, why not simply add the new one, instead of clearing all of them and rebuilding from the database?

Comment: I did little bit of hacking.
thanks for the reply .i kept your suggestion in mind and removed the part of code where i was rebuilding textviews from based on the elements i get.
Now what i did is that i'm inserting the newly added value into the database but not depending on the database to retrive and display it but i created new textview and i'm directly getting the text from edittext and setting it to new textview that i created and displaying it.it worked :)
Thank you all for valuable input